# How to change TextInputEditText style based on Active state

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I'm working on material `TextInputEditText` with it's state capture.

[image]

Above pitcher says `TextInputEditText` behaviour based on it's state.

we can use below styles

```
@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox

@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox
```

My question is there are different state like **Resting state, Focus State, Active state , Error state and disable state** How can we change `TextInputEditText` ***style*** based on these state.
providing example code is much appreciate

Comment: You can't change the style programmatically but you can change at runtime each attributes (stroke, background, colors...)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no direct method to update styles dynamically.

If your intention is to change the Style of your `TextInputEditText` dynamically and you are ok with using a trusted library, then I would suggest using [Paris from Airbnb.](https://github.com/airbnb/paris)

Paris lets you define and apply styles programmatically to Android views, including custom attributes.

You can set styles as simple as

```
myView.style(R.style.MyStyle)
```

Try it out and let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of these, for example, that line under input. You can change them by changing colors in the colors.xml resource.

Comment: So it will change style based on state, at runtime ?

Comment: Yes, it' will load colors when it starts. if you can not see new edit's in preview in Android Studio. You can close it and open it or change the preview theme.

Comment: Yes colors we can change. but my question can we change style ?